# Oracle Sql with subqueries

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm using the same scott schema.the questiion goes like this.
Display the empno,sal,TA,DA,HRA,Total allowances,Insurance,TDS,Netdeductions,Netsal with descriptive labels.

here Ta is 30% of sal, DA is 40% of sal,hra is 50% of sal, insurance is 5%sal and tds is 5%sal.
Total allowances is ta + da+ hra. total deductions is ins + tds
now netsal is (sal + allowances-total deductions)

I'm trying to achieve this using with statement

```
WITH T1 AS
 (SELECT (30 / 100 * SAL) AS TA FROM EMP),
T2 AS
 (SELECT (40 / 100 * SAL) AS DA FROM EMP),
T3 AS
 (SELECT (50 / 100 * SAL) AS HRA FROM EMP)
SELECT Empno, TA, DA, HRA, (ta + da + hra)
  FROM EMP, T1, T2, T3
 group by empno;
```

something like this.The logic is wrong I can understand that.

Comment: Why in subqueries and why are there no table joins? would select *, 30 / 100 * SAL) AS TA ,(40 / 100 * SAL) AS DA , (50 / 100 * SAL) AS HRA from emp give the same result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do this in a single query:

```
select e.*, (ta + da + hra) as total_allowances,
       (sal + (ta + da + hra) - (ins + tds)) as net_salary
from (select empno, (sal * 30/100) as ta, (sal * 40/100) as da, 
             (sal * 50/100) as hra,
             (sal * 0.05) as ins,
             (sal * 0.05) as tds
      from emp
     ) e;
```

I don't understand what the `group by` is for.  You have no aggregation functions and with a table name like `emp`, I would expect each row to have a unique value for `empno`.

Comment: Works for me..though I was trying to do it using the "with" clause anywaz thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
select empno,
       sal,
       .3 * sal as ta,
       .4 * sal as da,
       .5 * sal as hra,
       .05 * sal as insurance,
       .05 * sal as tds,
       (.3 * sal) + (.4 * sal) + (.5 * sal) as total_allowances,
       (.05 * sal) + (.05 * sal) as total_deductions,
       sal + ((.3 * sal) + (.4 * sal) + (.5 * sal)) - ((.05 * sal) + (.05 * sal)) as netsal
  from emp
```

I don't know what you're trying to achieve the WITH clause. Your t1/t2 queries are separately performing each calculation throughout the whole table. You can do each calculation in the same query. And it does not appear that any more than one table is involved, so you do not need any joins.